# Pass "this" element to JS function with "javascript:" URL

Tags: javascript, html, url

In short, I want to do

```
<a href="javascript:edit(this, 123)">Edit thing</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="edit(this, 123)">Edit thing</a>
```

where `this` would be the `<a />`, and 123 is an id. Why? It's much cleaner. Is there any way?

Comment: It's even cleaner to keep JavaScript out of your HTML altogether.

Comment: [JavaScript URIs are bad](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)

Comment: have you though on using jQuery?

Comment: @David: I am actually, the real code looks like `onclick="edit($(this), 123)"` hehe ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about we keep things semantic?

`<button type="button" id="edit"> Edit this </button>`

and then add some javascript somewhere

```
document.getElementById("edit").addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  // do edit logic
}, false);
```

You'll have issues with `addEventListener` in legacy browsers. Feel free to use [flow](http://flowjs.com/download/) to fix `addEventListener`

I also recommend you read about

- [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)
- [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

And choose one of those two techniques.

Also please don't hard code id's into your functions like that. Your `edit` button should know what it's editing by relative position in the DOM. it should be easy to find the *semantic id* that is on the *correct element* by a simple bit of DOM traversal.

Comment: If we're going into being semantic, the button should be created using JavaScript/DOM as well.

Comment: @MichalGorny that's different. I would create a `<button type="submit">` and change the `"type"` to `"button"` using JS personally. The way you handle non-JS depends on whether your progressively enhancing or making your js unobtrusive.

Comment: Progressive Enhancement and Unobtrusive JavaScript is great, but not the first thing I would worry about in this legacy admin interface. Could you please give a (non-HTML5) example of how to retrieve the ID? Because the best way I've found is to parse `id/class="id-123"` :(

Comment: @Znarkus depends what the ID means in terms of the rest of your markup. And the rest of your data.

Comment: @Raynos: It's the unique identifier for what should be edited, it maps to a database record. The link is presented with a table row of data.

Comment: @Znarkus you probably want it as a hidden input or instead have your function ask the database to edit the record by name rather then uuid

Comment: @Raynos: Btw, I'm not sure I understand your last paragraph. Do you suggest I create a lookup table *semantic id/element index* -> *record ID/record data*? And oh, forgot to say "thank you" :)

Comment: @Raynos let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2732/discussion-between-znarkus-and-raynos)

Comment: I will accept this answer as I agree that inline JS like the above is bad even for this; for one thing you can't change the ID with JS if you need to (I needed to). But I'm still waiting on the great solution without inline JS..